# Booting Linux from RAM

Tags: linux, boot, boot-loader, ram

I want to find a cross-distro solution for setting linux up to boot from RAM. What this involves in essence would be copying an existing installation of linux one way or another over to the RAM (to ramfs or tmpfs; that would be user preference, although I prefer ramfs, because after doing some minimal benchmarking it seemed to me to be *quicker* than tmpfs), then booting off the RAM as if it were a normal disk. This naturally has to happen while the bootloader is starting the system up (before or after loading the kernel from **/boot**).

The second part would involve periodically (say once per hour perhaps) and on shutdown, saving the data from the RAM to the disk, so that system changes won't be lost upon restart due to the volatile nature of modern RAM.

The ideal bootloader to do this from would be Grub2 and the way I envisioned this happening is thus:

First, prepare the system (copy the system to a different folder/hard drive), make all the symlinks for the directories you do not want on the ramdrive (like **/boot** and **/usr/share/man** (and on arch, **/var/cache/pacman**)), then edit the fstab appropriately for this boot setup, after that compress this modified version of the system into an image file (**.iso** or **.img** or similar) or into an archive (**tar.gz2**, **lzma**, **bz2**...) and then on boot, load the contents of that image/archive onto a ramfs/tmpfs (and then on shutdown, backup(rename) the image/archive that was booted from, then compress the contents of the ramfs to an image/archive to replace the old one.)

I imagine it shouldn't be very hard to achieve this, if one knows how, and of course, I'm open to alternative approaches than the approach I described, if it gets the job done.

I need to know what system files would need to be altered for this to work (the only one I am aware of is fstab), how to make the iso/img or archive, how to load it onto a ramdrive at boot time, and how to finally boot from it.

(Note: For those unaware of why I would want to do this, it is for the speed benefit. Any file loaded onto the RAM will load/execute almost instantly. It is many times over faster than any SSD, but of course comes at the price that you need to have enough RAM to spare to contain your system on it)

Comment: You've described most of it.  I think the missing link is using an [initramfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs) to uncompress the image.  Or likely you could just use an initramfs for the whole thing (it pretty much is what you want), I do not think they are limited in terms of scope nor do they have to hand off to anything (I could be wrong).  Getting it to save state at shutdown (no matter how you do this) is probably going to be an awkward task, however...

Comment: You have a step-by-step guide in the next link: http://reboot.pro/topic/14547-linux-load-your-root-partition-to-ram-and-boot-it/

Comment: [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm) does this sort of thing, using [squashfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) and [aufs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs). See the somewhat out of date [How Puppy Works](http://www.puppylinux.com/development/howpuppyworks.html) for a general overview.

Comment: tinycore also does it.

Comment: @goldilocks - seconded. You never need mount over initramfs if you don't want to - it's just the common thing to do. `fstab` and all the rest are in there too. Doing the save restore shouldn't be very different from a hibernate/suspend operation either. Basically all of those *persistent live discs* are just squashed rootfs images that mount a home. That's another way to do it *(and initramfs can be squashed, too)* but it's probably most simple just not to `switch_root`.

Comment: Following up what @YoMismo mentioned, I tried to, but cannot use that guide as it requires me to have mkinitramfs. My arch system comes with mkinitcpio to make the initramfs for my system.

Comment: @Cestarian - don't sweat it - just poke around in there. It's just a root filesystem. Extract the contents of one like `mkdir /tmp/cpio; cd /tmp/cpio; cpio </path/to/initramfs/image` and explore. The `mkinitramfs` is probably doing the same stuff as `mkinitcpio` - I use the latter, by the way. *(if it's compressed you might have to use whatever compression utility is necessary to uncompress it first, by the way)*

Comment: There is a way to do this in arch (based on slitaz) and for now I guess I might as well just turn into that direction.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1215085

But even if this works, it is not the cross-distro solution I was looking for (exactly because it is common that distros use a different programs for creating their initramfs (if they even use initramfs by default at all))

But a possible answer would be a guide that covers how to do it on any one of these programs (I don't know all of them, I know mkinitcpio, mkinitramfs and mkinitrd only)

Comment: To decompress initrd you can `gzip -dc initrd|cpio -id` to compress once you have modified it go to the directory where you decompressed initrd and execute `find . |cpio -H newc -o > YourNewinitrd;gzip YourNewinitrd;mv YourNewinitrd.gz YourNewinitrd` you have the guide to do it in the next link https://openvz.org/Modifying_initrd_image

Comment: That seems straightforward enough, we're getting somewhere, but there is one flaw, many distros will remake the initrd image if the kernel is updated through the package manager. (I don't know if this is actually necessary or not) we're on the right track though.

(For example, maybe it would be possible to place an image file on the boot drive with the linux installation, and then modify the script that the mkinitrd program uses when it remakes the initrd so that it will always apply this functionality to newly created initrd images)